# Iterate through python dictionary and edit all strings with key.

Tags: python, dictionary

In a dictionary called 'data' I have a nested dictionary with key 'meetings'. Some example data is below.

```
   'meetings':[  
          {  
         u'StartDate':u'09/06/2016',
         u'EndDate':u'12/13/2016',
         u'InstructorName':u'Staff',
         u'MeetingNumber':1,
         u'Days':u'MoWeFr',
         u'Times':         u'8:30         AM - 10:00         AM',
         u'TopicDescr':None,
         u'Location':u'3302 MH'
      }
   ],
```

I am trying to iterate through the whole dictionary and edit the 'Location' string so that it is only the building key which in the case above is 'MH' so all that would involve is removing everything up until the space and the space. The code I have no, but isn't working is below.

```
for meetings in data['meetings']:
    for location in meetings['Location']:
        location = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", "", location)
```

I think that this might be a scope problem as when I try and print the location later it still prints the entire 'Location' string, which in the case above would be '3302 MH'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not actually updating the dictionary. And the inner loop is not needed:

```
for meetings in data['meetings']:
    meetings['Location'] = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]+", "", meetings['Location'])
```

If the format of the `Location` values is consistent to what you've shown, you may also split by space and get the last item instead of a regular expression substitution:

```
for meetings in data['meetings']:
    meetings['Location'] = meetings['Location'].split()[-1]
```